# Playing mp3 file emdedded in html issue in android

Tags: android

While recording mp3 audio with below code and embedding it in html, the audio doesnot play in browser:

```
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile("filepath");
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                    mRecorder.start();
                    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();


protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaColumns.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));

 }
```

But if I change it to

```
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile("filepath");
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                    mRecorder.start();
                    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
```

the sound plays in the browser but with much disturbance.

i.e. replacing outputformat with MPEG_4 and AudioEncoder with AudioEncoder.AAC

Can anyone suggest what format works perfectly for html embedding in android?